# Factorization in formal power series versus in convergent power series over the complexes

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, several-complex-variables

Let $R=\mathbb C\{x_1,...,x_n\}\subset S=\mathbb C [[x_1,...,x_n]]$ denote the ring of convergent, respectively formal, power series over $\mathbb C$.
Suppose $f\in R$ is irreducible in $R$. Does it remain irreducible in $S$?

Comment: About the definition of $R$: Convergent _where_????

Comment: This comes down a question like if $\{a_i\}$ and $\{b_i\}$ are such that $\limsup \sqrt[n]{|c_n|}>0$ where $\displaystyle c_n=\sum_{i+j=n}a_ib_j$ then is it true that $\limsup \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}>0$ and $\displaystyle \limsup \sqrt[n]{|b_n|}$?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich This is the local ring of the complex manifold $\mathbb{C}^n$ at the origin. It means power series with positive radius of convergence.

Comment: [Crossposted on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/370621/factorization-in-formal-power-series-versus-in-convergent-power-series-over-the). When crossposting, it is important to link all versions together to prevent duplicating work.